# Querying Mongo Collection using QueryBuilder in Mongo 3.3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

Our code with mongo-java-driver 3.0.4  used to be like -

```
DBCollection dbCollection = mongoClient.getDB(databaseName).getCollection(collectionName);
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
/** queryBuilder.put() for building the query */
DBCursor dbCursor = dbCollection.find(queryBuilder.get());
while(dbCursor.hasNext()) {
    DBObject dbObject = dbCursor.next();
    // add entries to a list of TDocument type
}
```

Converting this to the mongo-java-driver 3.3.0, I ended up with this -

```
MongoCollection<TDocument> collection = database.getCollection(collectionName, TDocument.class); //where TDocument is custom document class of ours
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder();
/** queryBuilder.put() for building the query */
FindIterable<TDocument> tDocumentList = collection.find(queryBuilder.get()); //this is not compiling
for (TDocument element : tDocumentList) {
    names.add(element.getName()); //addition to some list of TDocument type
}
```

But the point is I am still not able to compile the source for the `find` operation on the MongoDB collection that I have defined.

What needs to be corrected here? I would want to stick to any preferred implementation that helps in upgrading mongo to 3.3.0+.

***Edit*** - My `TDocument` class (named differently below from the lib name) class is a simple POJO as -

```
public class TDocType {

    private TDocType() {
    }

    String one;

    @NotNull
    String name;

    String third;

    String fourth;

    // getter and setter for all the above
}
```

Comment: how does your TDocument looks like ? Does that extends DBObject ? Add that class to the post.

Comment: @Veeram added, wasn't sure why it would be required.

Comment: you can cast that to collection.find((Bson)queryBuilder.get())

Comment: Veeram Vincent can you have a look a this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179940/) as well? would mark a solution to this based on the consistent approach that can be followed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast to Bson.

```
 FindIterable<TDocument> tDocumentList = collection.find((Bson)queryBuilder.get());
```

Update:: 
Change to use the filters from Mongo 3.3.0

```
Bson filter = Filters.eq("field", "value");
FindIterable<TDocument> tDocumentList = collection.find(filter);
```

Comment: can you have a look a this (stackoverflow.com/questions/40179940) as well? would mark a solution to this based on the consistent approach that can be followed

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your query builder by a org.bson.Document like this :

```
Document query = new Document();
query.put(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

And then

```
FindIterable<TDocument> tDocumentList = collection.find(query); //this is not compiling
```

Comment: Correcting the last line of code -> `query.get()` doesn't work either, requires a `key` of `Object` type

Comment: my bad, it's just query not query.get()

Comment: can you have a look a this (stackoverflow.com/questions/40179940) as well? would mark a solution to this based on the consistent approach that can be followed