# QueryBuilder and BasicDBObjectBuilder usage in MongoDB 3.3.0 above

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

***PART 1***

Following up solutions to [Querying Mongo Collection using QueryBuilder in Mongo 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178038/querying-mongo-collection-using-querybuilder-in-mongo-3-3-0/40179222#40179222)
, I tried implementing the suggested methods to implement `collection.find()`. But was stuck with different parameters been passed a `BasicDBObjectBuilder` to the same as follows -

```
BasicDBObjectBuilder queryBuilder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();

query.getParams().entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> queryBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));


BasicDBObjectBuilder outputQuery = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start();
outputQuery.add(nameKey, 1);
```

---

This doesn't compile :

```
FindIterable<TDocType> tDocTypeList = collection.find(queryBuilder.get(), outputQuery.get());
```

---

This also won't compile :

```
FindIterable<TDocType> tDocTypeList = collection.find((Bson)queryBuilder.get(), (Bson)outputQuery.get());
```

---

And this won't compile either :

```
org.bson.Document queryBuilder = new org.bson.Document();

query.getParams().entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> queryBuilder.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

org.bson.Document outputQuery = new org.bson.Document();
outputQuery.put(nameKey, 1); 

FindIterable<TDocType> tDocTypeList = collection.find(queryBuilder, outputQuery);
```

> **Question** - How do I specify a `projection` for the results required out of `find()` from collections?

---

***PART 2***

At one end I can simply replace mongo 3.0.4 java driver's code  -

```
DBObject dbObject = collection.findOne(new QueryBuilder().put(ids).is(id).get())
```

to

```
Bson filter = Filters.eq(ids, id);
TDocType doc = collection.find(filter).first();
```

Now if we have an implementation where we build query through an iteration as in the sample code -

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : query.getParams().entrySet()) {
    // this is where its building the query
    if(some condition) {
        queryBuilder.put(entry.getKey()).is(entry.getValue()); 
    }
    if(some other condition) {
        queryBuilder.put(entry.getKey()).in(query.getValues());
    }
}
```

> ***Question*** - Is there a way to implement such *appending query Filters*
>   with current mongo 3.3.0+ as well?

Comment: i don't have a solution for now, but look at the JavaDoc https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/, there is no method find(Document, Document), so that's normal it does not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of find method is result type. Try as below.

```
FindIterable<TDocType> tDocTypeList = dbCollection.find(filter, TDocType.class);
```

Update for projection

```
FindIterable<TDocType> tDocTypeList = dbCollection.find(filter, TDocType.class).projection(outputQuery);
```

Update for appending filters

```
List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : query.getParams().entrySet()) {
        // this is where its building the query
   if (some condition){
       filters.add(Filters.eq(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
   }
   if (some other condition){
       filters.add(Filters.in(entry.getKey(), query.getValues()));
   }
}
FindIterable<TDocType> docType = dbCollection.find(Filters.and(filters));
```

Comment: how does this solve the `projection` problem from part1?

Comment: you can use fluent methods and try some thing like    dbCollection.find((Bson)queryBuilder.get(), TDocType.class).projection(outputQuery);

Comment: Thanks. That helps