# MongoClient , MongoDatabase to pojo Fetch data and display

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

Spec : mongodb-driver-3.3.0.jar,Mongodb Enterprise (Eval),jdk1.7

I have specifically written in 3.0 version of MongoAPI  to successfully connect to Db and INSERT data of bulk typos.

Statement: Insert Data to MongoDB Successfully using Mongo-Java API 3.0 using 
MongoClient , MongoDatabase

Problem : Need to fetch the Data from MongoDB using API MongoClient , MongoDatabase  and load the same to a List.

Question : Yah../G..gled / Mong...  and could not a single example for this simple solution

Does any body have a Code snippet to share....would be thankfull for the same.

Comment: Is [this page](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/#get-a-collection) from the documentation helping somehow?

Comment: What issues do you see while fetching data ? Add your code that you've tried.

Comment: MongoClientURI mClientURI = null;
String urlnsql = null;
try {
urlnsql = "mongodb://ABCDSERVER : 27007/?maxPoolSize= 10");
mClientURI = new MongoClientURI(urlnsql );
mClient = new MongoClient(mClientURI);
ndbmsConnx = mClient.getDatabase(nsqlx.getDbNameofNsqldB());   
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
  mClientURI = null;   
}

Comment: ndbmsConnx.getCollection("myTestCollection");                                                      
next  what  & how to get data/fetch from this collection to  POJO ????

Comment: I recently answered somthing similar. However you have to combine the answers from both posts. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179940/querybuilder-and-basicdbobjectbuilder-usage-in-mongodb-3-3-0-above/40181539#40181539 to get your result iterable with your pojo type and then use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246302/finding-distinct-from-collections-in-mongodb/40246563#40246563 to get the iterator from the result from previous step and finally, add and map to the pojo list.

Comment: Marco  : Yes That the Typos i am using and need ,3.3.0 API to move back all of the Data from Collection into a POJO ( list of Beans) for UI display purpose....